# How to create a form with modal windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I know how to create a form, I know how to create a modal window. My concern is to combine the two.

For the moment I managed to make sure that at the click on the first element of research, a window opens.

However I have to do that on every element of the form. How to associate each search element with its own modal window? Do I have to repeat the javascript code as many times as research items, or is there a cleaner way? thank you so much

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Lorsque l'on clique sur show on affiche la fenêtre modale
  $('#show').click(function(e) {
    //On désactive le comportement du lien
    e.preventDefault();
    showModal();
  });

  // Lorsque l'on clique sur le fond on cache la fenetre modale   
  $('#fond').click(function() {
    hideModal();
  });

  // Lorsque l'on modifie la taille du navigateur la taille du fond change
  $(window).resize(function() {
    resizeModal()
  });
});

function showModal() {
  var id = '#modal';
  $(id).html('Voici ma fenetre modale<br/><a href="#" class="close">Fermer la fenetre</a>');

  // On definit la taille de la fenetre modale
  resizeModal();

  // Effet de transition     
  $('#fond').fadeIn(1000);
  $('#fond').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
  // Effet de transition   
  $(id).fadeIn(2000);

  $('.popup .close').click(function(e) {
    // On désactive le comportement du lien
    e.preventDefault();
    // On cache la fenetre modale
    hideModal();
  });

  function hideModal() {
    // On cache le fond et la fenêtre modale
    $('#fond, .popup').hide();
    $('.popup').html('');
  }
}

function resizeModal() {
  var modal = $('#modal');
  // On récupère la largeur de l'écran et la hauteur de la page afin de cacher la totalité de l'écran
  var winH = $(document).height();
  var winW = $(document).width();

  // le fond aura la taille de l'écran
  $('#fond').css({
    'width': winW,
    'height': winH
  });

  // On récupère la hauteur et la largeur de l'écran
  var winH = $(window).height();
}
```

```css
#fond {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: #0F3C68;
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  left: 40%;
}

#modal {
  width: 760px;
  height: 440px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fond"></div>
<div id="modal" class="popup"></div>
<a href="#" id="show" class="bouton_recherche">Ville(s) de Départ</a>
```

Comment: Pas besoin de répeter le js, tu peut mettre plusieurs div dans ton modal, avec display:none, et mettre le bon div visible selon le lien qui a été cliqué.

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé Please reply in the English language.

Comment: what you want to show with every element against an element? would it be a simple message or modal may contain multiple form controls as well?

Comment: Oups.. no need to repeat js, you could just put several hidden div inside your modal, and when a link is clicked, display the right div depending on which link has been clicked.

Comment: Thank you François I'm french too :p Thank you Arslanlqbal. Inside the modal windows there would be checkboxes for the form. One of them would contain a calendar.

Comment: I see what you mean François. I hope to succeed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code for the same model but will have to pass the data you want to show against every element of the form. I have updated your showModal method which now accepts message as input and shows that message. You can use the same methodology for complex modal as well i.e. pass some parameter as input to the modal and based on that parameters, show the appropriate response to user

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Lorsque l'on clique sur show on affiche la fenêtre modale
  $('#message1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showModal('First Message Clicked');
  });
  
  $('#nessage2').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showModal('Second Message Clicked');
  });


  // Lorsque l'on clique sur le fond on cache la fenetre modale   
  $('#fond').click(function() {
    hideModal();
  });

  // Lorsque l'on modifie la taille du navigateur la taille du fond change
  $(window).resize(function() {
    resizeModal()
  });
});

function showModal(message) {
  var id = '#modal';
  $(id).html('<br>' + message + '<br/><a href="#" class="close">Close</a>');

  // On definit la taille de la fenetre modale
  resizeModal();

  // Effet de transition     
  $('#fond').fadeIn(1000);
  $('#fond').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
  // Effet de transition   
  $(id).fadeIn(2000);

  $('.popup .close').click(function(e) {
    // On désactive le comportement du lien
    e.preventDefault();
    // On cache la fenetre modale
    hideModal();
  });

  function hideModal() {
    // On cache le fond et la fenêtre modale
    $('#fond, .popup').hide();
    $('.popup').html('');
  }
}

function resizeModal() {
  var modal = $('#modal');
  // On récupère la largeur de l'écran et la hauteur de la page afin de cacher la totalité de l'écran
  var winH = $(document).height();
  var winW = $(document).width();

  // le fond aura la taille de l'écran
  $('#fond').css({
    'width': winW,
    'height': winH
  });

  // On récupère la hauteur et la largeur de l'écran
  var winH = $(window).height();
}
```

```css
#fond {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: #0F3C68;
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  left: 40%;
}

#modal {
  width: 760px;
  height: 440px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fond"></div>
<div id="modal" class="popup"></div>
<a href="#" id="message1">First Message</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" id="nessage2">Second Message</a>
```

Comment: Thank you ArslanIqbal but I don't understand your message :(

Comment: What do you mean? are you not able to pass message or what? @Carine

Comment: Do not be "aggressive". I am just totally beginner in javascript and not very good in English I try to adapt.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood

Comment: I just lack technique to be able to understand your message. I'm working on it...

Comment: After working a lot, I understood your message and your code. Thank you very much!!! @ArslanIqbal

Comment: But my html inside the modal is necessarily in the js file? These are forms inside. Thanks !

Comment: @Carine you can use either template files for rendering your required html or you can just show and hide the relevant html based on the input. The base concept is the same i.e. pass some information based on the element selected and based on that information perform some action.